# find count of students based on interest

Tags: mysql, sql, join, rdbms

> Write a sql query that prints domain interest and number students who
> are interested in that domain.
>
> ```
> +------+----------+----------+
> | sno  | sub1     | sub2     |
> +------+----------+----------+
> | s1   | ds       | networks |
> | s2   | os       | ds       |
> | s3   | ds       | os       |
> | s4   | networks | db       |
> | s5   | os       | networks |
> | s6   | db       | ds       |
> | s7   | networks | os       |
> | s8   | db       | os       |
> +------+----------+----------+
> ```
>
> Expected output:
>
> ```
> +----------+-------------+
> | sub1     |Totalstudents|
> +----------+-------------+
> | db       |           3 |
> | ds       |           4 |
> | networks |           4 |
> | ob       |           5 |
> +----------+-------------+
> ```

This is what he/she has tried:

```
select sub1, count(sub1) 
from student 
group by sub1;
```

then tried subquery as

```
select a.sub1
     , count(a.sub1) 
      ,count(b.sub1) 
from student a, student b 
where a.sub1=b.sub2 
group by a.sub1, b.sub2;
```

Comment: First UNION ALL, then GROUP BY its result.

Comment: Don't ask us to do your homework. [Help] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Doesn't matter. See the links. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Mayur, do what jarlh asked you to do then post it here again.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this, obviously more clumsy than UNION ALL (I'm learning SQL, so any comments are more than welcome).

```
SELECT 
    a.sub AS Subject, a.c + b.c AS Count
FROM
    ((SELECT 
        sub1 AS sub, COUNT(sub1) AS c
    FROM
        students
    GROUP BY sub1
    ORDER BY sub1) AS a
    JOIN (SELECT 
        sub2 AS sub, COUNT(sub2) AS c
    FROM
        students
    GROUP BY sub2
    ORDER BY sub2) AS b USING (sub))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize [`UNION ALL`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-union.php) and [`GROUP BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_groupby.asp):

```
SELECT 
  sub AS sub1, 
  COUNT(*) AS Totalstudents 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      sub1 AS sub 
    FROM 
      students 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
      sub2 AS sub 
    FROM 
      students
  ) AS t 
GROUP BY 
  sub;
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+---------------+
| sub1     | Totalstudents |
+----------+---------------+
| db       |             3 |
| ds       |             4 |
| networks |             4 |
| os       |             5 |
+----------+---------------+
```